# The existence of a copy of a random variable with conditional expectation constraint

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, existence-theorems

Let there be two random variables  and  with a certain joint copula. Is it always true that there is another random variable  independent from  such as the vectors $(X,Y)$ and $(X,Z)$ have the same law?

Comment: What do you mean by "joint copula"? "joint distribution"?

Comment: I mean that the r.v X and Y are not independent (their joint distribution is not trivial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, suppose $X=Y$ a.s. and that they are non-degenerate. If we want $(X, Z)$ to have the same joint distribution as $(X, Y)$, we must also have $X=Z$ a.s. and hence $Y=Z$ a.s. Then $Y$ and $Z$ can obviously not be independent.